# Is a cracked roof title considered cosmetic

Tags: roof, roofing

I'm in the inspection step when buying a new property. The inspector found a few cracks on the roof. It's a tile roof and is 23 years old. A roof leak was found but it only reaches the attic... How much time realistically before I need a new roof and are the cracked titles considered cosmetic or should they be fixed or credited before I close?

Comment: What is the tile material?

Answer (score 5):

Tile roofs can last anywhere from 35 to 50 years, depending on the roofing material installed under the tile. Cracked tile often happen from people walking on them during pressure cleaning or gutter cleaning. Some cracked tiles could even be from the initial installation as inspectors don't usually inspect each tile.
There are special adhesives designed to fix a cracked tile. It is applied with a caulk gun and prevents you from having to break loose the old tile to remove it, which can damage and crack the membrane below.  The adhesive comes in many roofing colors.

You should definitely get the roof leak that you found corrected before closing.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the owner to fix the cracked tiles by settlement date. Tiles crack, it is just a part of the  maintenance. My house also has tiles and one cracked during a heavy hail. Make sure you check your roof at least once a year or after storm/hail etc.